# jQuery $(this) Problem, wrong object

Tags: jquery, plugins

i using this code to show a title

```
$(".line").mopTip({
'w':150, 
'style':"overOut", 
'get': $(this).attr("title")
});
```

but as title I get the title of page... what do I wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're missing context

Comment: Apparently `this` is the document object in there, maybe the plugin you're using is not correctly selecting the element... Which plugin are you using exactly?

Comment: what are you expecting $(this) to be?

Comment: @Deleteman mopTip it is a japanise plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `this` inside the <s>document</s> window scope, that is why it returns the document title. To get the title of each line you have to loop over each one of them.

```
$(".line").each(function(){
    //inside the each the scope of this refers to the current line
    $(this).mopTip({
        'w':150, 
        'style':"overOut", 
        'get': $(this).attr("title")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("title")
```

This gets the attribute "title" of the page, it always does when called in the document.

If the class "line" is the target, replace `$("this")` with `$(".line")`

Answer (score 0):

For set content '**mopTip**' use construction

`... = $( setting.get ).html();`

'get' - init in params.

And you code convert to

`$( "Title of page" ).html();`

In other words, in params 'get' must be selector... or function which return selector. Correct architecture of HTML-page. Or correct code of jQuery-plugin. Or wrap init to each().